# How do time shift (virtual clock) Software like Time Machine work?

Tags: testing, time

Time shift software like [Time Machine](http://www.solution-soft.com/products/time-machine) enables you to test your application based on past or future time. Time Machine® guarantees no modification are needed in the database and the application.

I was just curious about how this software works internally. Does anyone have any thoughts about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These applications intercept the date and time calls of the application and return a date and time from a virtual clock.

> Time Machine intercepts your file system’s date and time calls. If the
>   caller is configured with a virtual clock and the program is not on
>   the exclusion list, virtual time is returned; otherwise system time is
>   returned.

Source (for the mentioned Time Machine software): http://www.solution-soft.com/sites/default/files/wysiwyg/TMDataSheet.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I actually wrote one from scratch for windows.  I have to say it is an interesting endeavor, and the information is available on the web to write one from scratch.

The code I designed the intercept off of is [out on codeproject](https://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=2082&PageFlow=FixedWidth).

The Three Functions I hooked were:

1. [GetSystemTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724390(v=vs.85).aspx)
2. [GetLocalTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724338(v=vs.85).aspx)
3. [GetSystemTimeAsFileTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724397(v=vs.85).aspx)

These were the only ones I needed to capture to replace all time calls within .net.

The process isn't so much hard as it is difficult to maintain, especially if you are operating on a virtual system like Citrix.